# How to fix invalid conversion error? (char to const char*)

Tags: c, data-structures

I am trying to make a program (school task) for an item shop. This is the function to search the order id and delete the node with the order id inputted by user. The function works just fine when i used order number but when i used id, the program refuse to compile and it says '[Error] invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char*' in the if line. How to fix? pls help.

```
void takeOrder(){
    if (!head){
        printf("“--- There is No Order in The List ---");
        return;
    }
    char id[7];
    view();
    printf("Input the order id to take [case insensitive]: ");
    scanf("%[^\n]", &id); fflush(stdin);

    data *temp=head;
    if(strcmpi(head->id, id)==0){
        head=head->next;
        temp->next=NULL;
        head->prev=NULL;
        free(temp);
    }
    else if(strcmpi(tail->id, id)==0){
        temp=tail;
        tail=tail->prev;
        tail->next=NULL;
        temp->prev=NULL;
        free(temp);
    }
    else{
        while(strcmpi(temp->id, id)!=0 && temp!=NULL){
            temp=temp->next;
            if(temp==NULL){
                break;
            }
        }
        if(temp==NULL){
            printf("The number you've selected is not available!\n");
            system("pause");
        }
        else{
            temp->prev->next=temp->next;
        temp->next->prev=temp->prev;
        temp->next=NULL;
        temp->prev=NULL;
        free(temp);
        }
    }
    counter--;  
}
```

Comment: Show the line where the error occurs and if any structure involved show it's definition.

Comment: What does the `data` type look like? Note that the compiler is complaining about converting a **single** `char`, not a `char*` to `const char*`…

Comment: `scanf("%[^\n]", &id);` is a problem for many reasons,: wrong argument, no input limit, no certain consumption of the following `'\n'`, no check of the return value.

Comment: `printf("“--- There is No Order in The List ---");` is suspicious with its non_ASCII character. `“`.

Answer (score 0):

pass the index of id to scanf :

```
 scanf("%[^\n]", &id); fflush(stdin);
```

use following :

```
scanf("%[^\n]", &id[0]); fflush(stdin);
```

or following :

```
scanf("%[^\n]",id); fflush(stdin);
```

Comment: Good 1st step.  The answer does fix [1 of the 4 problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48698136/how-to-fix-invalid-conversion-error-char-to-const-char#comment84395964_48698136).  Still OP needs to be more forth-coming on error message.